# Get Hierarchy data until last child - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, hierarchical-data

I have this table structure. I want to create a query for hierarchical data till last child only, no reference to parent again.

Table structure :

```
    ParentId    ChildId
    -------------------
    NULL        6000101
    6000101     6000102
    6000101     6000106
    6000101     6000107
    6000102     6000103
    6000102     6000104
    6000102     6000105
    6000103     6000101
    6000104     6000101
    6000105     6000101
    6000106     6000101
    6000106     6000102
    6000107     6000102
    6000107     6000105
```

[Current data structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOIRM.png)

Desired structure or result set:

```
    ParentId  ChildId 
    ---------------------
    NULL      6000101
    6000101   6000102
    6000101   6000106
    6000101   6000107
    6000102   6000103
    6000102   6000104
    6000102   6000105
```

[Desired result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft4TK.png)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry, but I tried formatting it but it does not work, should I use html tags to format ?

Comment: When editing, write the data in proper columns. Put 4 <space> character first in each row, and an empty row before.

Comment: Ok. Let me try. How to give a line break for each row ?

Comment: Empty row is only needed once, before the sample data section.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it work properly, but came up with the edited one.

Comment: Can also highlight the code block and press the curly brackets button `{}` (or CTRL+K)

Comment: I did and check the edited.

Comment: So a child record can have multiple parents?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?  It isn't clear to me what you're expecting your desired output to be.

Comment: Edit looks good.  As others have asked, what's the logic behind your expected results?  Why is the first child `ParentID = 6000102` considered, but not any of the others?

Comment: Please define how the relationship works between the ParentID and ChildID. Like @ErikusMaximus said, while visually you have shown the desired result, it is not clear on how the data relates to getting there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. Below answer what I need.
But just to clarify your queries, this is a multiple parent scenario where child can have more than one parent, like flowchart, I need to get a drill down data until last child, not referencing back to its any of the parent again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, one would use a recursive common table expression when querying a hierarchy, but since you have circular references in your data, you'll need to use a loop.

Assuming your source table is called "MyTable". You'll want to create a table (temp or otherwise) that will hold the cleaned up hierarchy:

```
create table MyHierarchy (
  ParentId int null
  ,ChildId int not null
  ,[Level] int not null
);
```

You'll then enter your root parent record and loop until you reach the circular references:

```
-- insert root parent record
insert into MyHierarchy
select
    *
    ,0 as [Level]
from
    MyTable
where
    ParentId is null;

-- loop until you reach a circular reference
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin
    insert into MyHierarchy
    select
        MyTable.*
        ,MyHierarchy.[Level] + 1 as [Level]
    from
        MyTable
        inner join
        MyHierarchy on MyTable.ParentId = MyHierarchy.ChildId
    where
        MyTable.ChildId not in (select ChildId from MyHierarchy)
end
```

This get's you almost all the way there. You have a record (`ChildId = 6000105`) that references multiple parents. Taking a bias towards a lower level, you can now use the `row_number()` function with a cte to get a unique relationship.

```
with cte as (
    select
        MyHierarchy.*
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MyHierarchy.ChildId ORDER BY parent.[Level], MyHierarchy.parentId) as RowNumber
    from
        MyHierarchy
        left join
        MyHierarchy parent on MyHierarchy.ParentId = parent.ChildId
)
select
    *
from
    cte
where
    RowNumber = 1
order by
    ParentId
    ,ChildId
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7089d/3

Comment: You are awesome. That works fine. Thank you very much.